# Large Binary Files & Git

Tags: git, binaryfiles, filemaker

We have a large line-of-business application based on Filemaker Pro 13. It consists of 50+ binary files ranging from 10MB to 5GB. I would like to use Git to manage versioning of this system. I understand that I can't leverage the best benefit of Git, which is text-based diff'ing, but Git and the rest of the surrounding ecosystem of tools would be beneficial to us. In my case, many of these files have small changes or restructurings that could be in any of the 50+ files for any "changeset" or node.

Is Git currently a good tool for managing a (relatively) fixed set of mutable binary files? Do I need an extension? If so, which? If not Git, what to use?

Comment: See [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/).

Comment: _"Is Git currently a good tool for managing a (relatively) fixed set of mutable binary files?"_   No. (but git-annex sounds like an interesting option.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of any plugins that would help (though I would LOVE to hear about them if they exist). We use Subversion at my company, but we run into the same issue: version control with large binary files is a P.I.T.A.

Normally what I will do with the larger files we work with is:

- Keep a version of the file in a folder outside of the working copy
- As I make changes to the FileMaker file, save the file as a clone and place that clone in the working copy

When you think about it, what you're really wanting to save in the repository when it comes to FileMaker is changes to the file structure itself, so saving a clone as you work will capture all of those changes. Since you're saving a clone out from the populated file, your populated copy will always mirror or be ahead of the version you keep in the working copy.

If you ever need to pull down a copy of the file from the repo and populate it, you can import the data from the populated version outside of the repo.

For a project with large files, you could use a structure like this:

```
- PopulatedFilesFolder/
    - FileName.fmp12
- ProjectFolderName/
    - FileName.fmp12
    ...
```

Where:
 - `PopulatedFilesFolder` holds all of your populated files and sits outside of the root of your working copy
 - `ProjectFolderName` is the root of your checked out working copy and  all of the files in it are clones

It's not ideal, but it's a method.